# Why are transition maps of principal bundles given by multiplications of elements of the group?

Tags: manifolds, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, equivariant-maps

It seems to be a common fact that transition maps of principal bundles are given by multiplication by a group element ([in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/383172/141291),for example.)

The setup is this: Consider a $G$-bundle $E \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} B$ and open sets $U,V$ with corresponding trivialisations
[image]

These induce trivialisations $\pi^{-1} (U \cap V) \overset{\varphi}{\rightarrow} (U \cap V) \times G$ and $\pi^{-1} (U \cap V) \overset{\psi}{\rightarrow} (U \cap V) \times G$, so we get a transition map

$$ \varphi \circ \psi^{-1} : (U \cap V) \times G \rightarrow (U \cap V) \times G$$

Why is this map necessarily given by (right) multiplication by an element of $G$?

It seems that the more general idea here is that any (equivariant) endomorphism of a $G$-torsor T (i.e. set on which $G$ acts freely and transitively)  is given by multiplication by a group element (as seems to be stated in the [first answer of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276146/why-are-equivariant-morphisms-of-g-torsors-necessarily-isomorphisms))

So let $\rho: T \rightarrow T$ be such a map. Fix an element $x \in T$ and let $g$ be the unique element of $G$ such that $\rho(x) = x.g.$

For any $y \in T$, there exists an unique element $h \in G$ such that $y = x.h$. Then

$$\rho(y) = \rho(x.h) = \rho(x).h = (x.g).h \neq (x.h).g = y.g,$$

in general. So why is the transition map given by multiplication by an element of $G$?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail, but the fact the order of multiplication is reversed in your last calculation suggests there is a mix-up somewhere between left and right actions (or equivalently, there is an inverse missing somewhere).

Comment: I always found this confusing but based on previous comment i believe it is mixup of left action on trivialization nd right action on torsos. There is a left (as well as right) multiplication on the trivialization. So in your trivialzation of the right G-torsor T, x maps to e (identity element of the group) and y maps to h. Then applying rho, rho(x) trivilizes to g and your calculation shows rho(y) trivialize to gh. So on the trivialization, rho corresponds to left multiple by g, since h got sent to gh

Comment: That makes sense, but for example https://math.mit.edu/~mbehrens/18.906spring10/prin.pdf states that $U \times G$ is equipped with a right action given by $(u,g).h= (u,gh)$...

Comment: (Continuing comment) Yes, as a G torsos we can consider UxG to be equipped with right G action. Let's for simplicity take U to be a point, so we have a map G->G that is right G-equivariant. So this map is  determined by where e goes to, say g. Then h=eh goes to gh, I.e h goes to gh, sot. If your group is abelian then this is is ri. But the isom between right G-torsors has to be LEFT multiplication by G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Continued from comments) The trivial bundle has a left and right action, and both are being used even if you want all torsors to be right torsors,  the MAP between two trivializations is given by LEFT multiplication. More details say as a G torsors we consider UxG to be equipped with right G action. Let's for simplicity take U to be a point, so we have a map G->G that is right G-equivariant. So it is determined by where e goes to, say g. Then h=eh goes to gh, by G equivariance and all the as actions is on right. I.e the MAP (not the torsor actiob) is left multiplication by g as h goes to gh. If your group is abelian then this is also a right multiplication obviously. If you look at end of p.2 prop 2.1 of the pdf by Mitchell, you see f(b) is acting on the left.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, this makes sense. So in the case of Mitchell's 2.1, if you have a _right_ equivariant map $\rho: U\times G \rightarrow U\times G$, the restriction of this map to $\{u\} \times G$ (for $u \in U$) is given by _left_ multiplication by some $g_u \in G$. So $\rho$ is completely determined by the assignment $f : U \rightarrow G$, $f(u) = g_u$. 

But there's no reason to expect $f$ to be constant, right? So then why do they claim in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383172/principal-g-bundles-over-the-circle) that the transition maps are given by elements of G?

Comment: I got it. In the post I linked, the regions $U$ are connected and the group $G$ is given the discrete topology, so $f:U \rightarrow G$, being continuous, must in fact be constant. That's why the transition functions are given by constants.